# Save Image in Open Chrome Tab

Tags: google-chrome, applescript

I have a script that opens images in a Chrome tab and I need it to save them to the Finder.

Only Chrome's user session has access to the images. Any script or Chrome plug-in that tries to directly download the images from their URLs in a way that is external to the user session receives a 403 error.

Is there a way to save the image in a tab that has been opened in Chrome via AppleScript to the Finder?

Answer (score 0):

While there appears to be no direct Applescript command to do this, the work around in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13422058/130427) can set the save directory after the save dialog is activated by a key stroke.